# I cannot knit a file to PDF, I have tried for 3 hours and now I'm lost, what to do?

Tags: r, latex, rstudio, tinytex

thank you for helping because at this point im hopeless.
I installed tinytex and i still get this message...
The error i get when trying to knit is:

```
processing file: Casestudy.Rmd
  |.......................                                               |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...............................................                       |  67%
label: setup (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |......................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: Casestudy.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS Casestudy.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Casestudy.tex --lua-filter "C:\Users\Tamás\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\pagebreak.lua" --lua-filter "C:\Users\Tamás\Documents\R\win-library\4.0\rmarkdown\rmarkdown\lua\latex-div.lua" --self-contained --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
tlmgr update --all --self
warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tamás/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
tlmgr.pl: package repository https://ctan.math.illinois.edu/systems/texlive/tlnet (not verified: gpg unavailable)
tlmgr.pl install: package already present: kpathsea
! warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
! ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt
! warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `c:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt' instead of a filename.

! warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `c:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt' instead of a filename.

! warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/win32/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/bin/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/share/texmf/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-local/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-dist/web2c;C:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf/web2c.
! ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:935: ...s\Tamás\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:858: no appropriate script or program found: fmtutil
! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! Running the command C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\fmtutil-user.exe

! kpathsea: Running mktexfmt pdflatex.fmt

! The command name is C:\Users\Tam<e1>s\AppData\Roaming\TinyTeX\bin\win32\mktexfmt

! warning: kpathsea: mktexfmt output `c:/Users/Tam<e1>s/AppData/Roaming/TinyTeX/texmf-var/web2c/pdftex/pdflatex.fmt' instead of a filename.

Error: LaTeX failed to compile Casestudy.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Casestudy.log for more info.
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In xfun::read_utf8(f2) :
  The file C:\Users\TAMS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSYF7O0\stderreec54b61a31 is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 1, 3, 7, 8
2: In xfun::read_utf8(f2) :
  The file C:\Users\TAMS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpSYF7O0\stderreec49286a7a is not encoded in UTF-8. These lines contain invalid UTF-8 characters: 1, 3, 7, 8
Execution halted
```

Comment: Can you somehow show what goes into your `rmarkdown` document?

Comment: It was a 'new rmarkdown file', only the defaults, basically nothing else. Since then, I found another important line: "I can't find the format file `pdflatex.fmt'!"

Comment: Do you have all the prerequisites installed? If so, have you ever `knit`ted an `rmakrdown` file before?